# - 'TextTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart' or defining a getter or field named 'subhead'. .subhead

Tags: xcode, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

Flutter throwing TextTheme subhead error,Wasted almost two days. Unable to find the solution.  Don't know why occurring it's too irritating.

[See the screenshot here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cBqs.png)

Comment: Could you add more information, such as a short code snippet that triggers yout current error?

Comment: I have added the screenshot above.

Answer (score 1):

In the newer versions of Flutter, they changed around the different textTheme properties, making the old ones deprecated. Going to your project and checking the source code (cmd + click on mac, ctrl + click on windows (I think?)) will show you the correct new term. For example, `textTheme.body1` is now `textTheme.bodyText2`.